# Recycle Bin Timer Job

Tags: wss-3.0, timer-jobs

The recycle bin timerjob is configured to run daily at 1.00 am . The CPU utilization of the database was nearly 90 %. When i checked the recycle job status it was initialized at 12.00 noon. Now the status has changed to failed. How do i debug what went wrong at what are the possible reasons and how to rectify it

Answer (score 1):

Check how much content is in the recycle bin. If you're dealing with alot of big files, try restoring some to the original library and manually executing the recycle bin clean up job. Continue deleting a small number of files at a time and running the clean up job until all files have been purged.

Alternatively, turn the second level recycle bin off, then on again (this will delete everything from the second level recycle bin for that web application, regardless of when it was added).

Here's a good reference on dealing with recycle bin clean up issues: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ajithas/archive/2009/09/08/deleting-very-large-objects-from-the-second-stage-recycle-bin.aspx.